# Read and merge row 6 and below from hundreds of csv files in R

Tags: r, csv

I have hundreds of csv files (all in a folder "Project A") each contains the same columns, but the first five rows are not part of the data frame.
I need to merge all the rows in every csv file starting from row 6, and create a master sheet in R. Here are my codes.

```
library(plyr)
library(readr)
myfiles <- list.files(path = "~/Projects/Project A", pattern = "*.csv", full.names = TRUE)
myfiles
do.call("rbind", lapply(myfiles, read.csv, header = TRUE))
```

How do I skip the first 5 rows? I know I should use `skip = 5`, but not sure where to put it or can it be integrated here.

Comment: `do.call("rbind", lapply(myfiles, read.csv, skip = 5))`
Should work. `read.csv` assumed that `header = TRUE` by default, `read.table` does not.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a good way to test this, but think this will work:

```
library(tidyverse)

do.call("rbind", lapply(myfiles, read.csv, header = TRUE)) %>% slice(5:n())
```

Or, as James pointed out:

```
do.call("rbind", lapply(myfiles, read.csv, skip = 5, header = TRUE))
```

Comment: rather than `slice` you could just add `skip = 5` to the extra function arguments supplied to `read.csv` which tells it to omit the first 5 lines.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know that. I added it to my post.